# Azure B2C - Use generated temporary password in Signup custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Is there a way to use the generated random password while creating the account using Signup Custom policies?.
I understand that this is possible using Graph API but we are looking at the possibilities using the policies.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the password a user would use to login to their account, then no. As detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes) the only thing custom policies can do with user passwords is write them to the directory.  You cannot read a user's password from custom policies (or from anywhere as far as I am aware).

I'm not sure which random password specifically is being referred to (if you are following an example, posting it may help), but you would have to store it elsewhere (which obviously carries security issues with it) and then retrieve it using an API of some sort during policy execution